# Unable to find Android SDK location for setting preference Eclipse

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse, adt

To start Android Development I installed..

JDK 7

Downloaded and installed Eclipse in **E:/** Drive on Windows 7

Then following the steps, *installed Android ADT using Eclipse*. 
Everything fine till now but on trying to set preference its not accepting any folder.

On looking other suggestions online i founded that there is some setup a *`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk`* but no such folder in my case.

Is my ***android-sdk*** in **E:/** Drive instead of **C:/**

I just got a folder (after ADT installation) :

E:\Software\JAVA Tools\eclipse-mobile-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685

i can't find any **'tools'** folder even (as eclipse preference requires)

Don't know what to do. Please suggest me something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello please follow the simple steps to install eclipse and Android SDK there is an ADT-bundle so it consists of all like

**1)** Eclipse where u no need to install

**2)** Android SDK ,

**3)**  ADT Plugins

So u simply Click on eclipse it will load automatically all like Android SDK and ADT plugins. So please follow the link to **[download](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)** the adt-bundle.

**Note :** Before that please install JDK .

Answer (score 0):

My friend, who will install `ANDROID SDK`? It neither comes with `JDK` or `Eclipse`. Please go through these for proper setup [link1](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), [link2](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)