# "Location of the Android SDK has not been set up in the preference". error

Tags: android

Location of the Android SDK has not been set up  in the preference.
These error is facing in eclipse  so give the solution   foe solving the issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find Android SDK location for setting preference Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173013/unable-to-find-android-sdk-location-for-setting-preference-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Open Eclipse then go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location and setup SDK path.